# How can I make nothing happen when hitting enter in a empty search/text box

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have an order page with a `search/text box`, in which I can filter by product name or code.

The issue I am having is that, when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the empty `search/text box`, then nothing should happen but the add items to order modal box pops up. This issue only happens, when using Internet Explorer. In Google Chrome,  everything works, like it should.

My code:

```
<div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></div>
  <input type="text" id="productFilter" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter by Product Name/Code" data-bind="textInput: productFilter">
</div>
<table id="orderContents" class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <!-- ko ifnot: enforceZeroQuantity -->
    <th style="width: 17%">
      <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs pull-left hidden-print" data-bind="click: toggleAllLineQuantityVarianceInfo, disable: isBusy, visible: orderHasQuantityVariance, attr: {title: expandOrContractTitle()}">
        <span class="fa" data-bind="css: {'fa-expand' : isAllQuantityVarianceInfoCollapsed(), 'fa-compress' : !isAllQuantityVarianceInfoCollapsed()}"></span>
      </button>
      <span class="visible-xs pull-right">Qty</span><span class="hidden-xs pull-right">Quantity</span>
    </th>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <th>
      Product
      <!-- ko ifnot: isReadOnly()-->
      <button id="addOrderLine" class="btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right hidden-print" data-bind="click: addOrderLine, disable: isBusy, visible: canAddOrderLines() || canAddLinesToDispatchedOrder()" title="Click to add a line to this order">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      </button>
      <button id="sortOrderLines" class="btn btn-info btn-xs pull-right hidden-print rightMargin" data-bind="click: toggleOrderLineSort, disable: isBusy, visible: canSortOrderLines" title="Click to sort the lines in this order">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span>
      </button>
      <button id="cancelSortOrder" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right hidden-print" data-bind="click: cancelOrderLineSort, disable: isBusy, visible: lineSortActive" title="Click to cancel the sort of the lines in this order">
        <span class="fa fa-remove"></span>
      </button>
      <button id="updateSortOrder" class="btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right hidden-print rightMargin" data-bind="click: updateLineSortOrders, disable: isBusy, visible: lineSortActive" title="Click to save the sort order">
        <span class="fa fa-save"></span>
      </button>
```

Can anyone see, where the mistake is? I just want to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the empty search box and I want nothing to happen, so the add items to order modal should not pop up.

Below is the code for the add to order modal and there are no form tags

```
function addOrderLine() {
                if (viewModel.orderState() !== "Template" && viewModel.orderIsLocked()) {
                    dynamicModal.showModal({
                        viewModel: {
                            title: 'Add Item(s) to Order',
                            closeModal: function() {
                                this.modal.close();
                            }
                        },
                        template: "/Content/components/order/modals/order-locked-modal.html",
                        context: viewModel
                    });
                    return;
                }
```

Comment: The title should give a short summary of the problem. In its current form, the title is not helpful.

Comment: Show us your model, how is the input field used?

Comment: Also is there a form tag anywhere by any chance?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for checking this out

Comment: is `productFilter` observable? does it have any subscriptions? what IE versions the problem hits? Does it gone if replace textInput with value binding ?